# Инкрементированая строка

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть ли у кого-нибудь код, который получает из строки допустим 'qwerty' следующую 'qwertz', а из строки 'qwertz' - 'qwerva'. Инкрементированую строку, если это можно назвать так.

Comment: Эм.. Но после "t" идёт "u", а не "v"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить простой алгоритм, который делает то же самое, но в алфавите `0-9a-z`.
Мы просто представляем слово, как число в 36ричной системе счисления:

```js
function next(word, increment = 1) {
  return (parseInt(word, 36)+increment).toString(36);
}

// Всё, что ниже, только для демонстрации, ответом является функция next

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');

const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');


prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => input.value = next(input.value, -1));
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => input.value = next(input.value));

{
  let h;
  startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    h&&clearInterval(h);
    h = setInterval(() => input.value = next(input.value), 120);
  });
  stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => h&&clearInterval(h));
}
```

```html
<button id=prevBtn>&lt;&lt;</button>
<input value="qwertx">
<button id=nextBtn>&gt;&gt;</button>
<br>
<button id=startBtn>Start</button>
<button id=stopBtn>Stop</button>
```

С другим алфавитом(включая, например русские буквы или исключая цифры), придётся то же самое делать вручную.

Comment: Хм.. В вопросе после "z" получается "a", а у тебя "0"...

Comment: @Qwertiy, `но в алфавите 0-9a-z`

Comment: А, точно, поленился прочитать текст... Я для "a-z" сделал. Но с вопросом всё равно не сходится...

Answer (score 1):

```js
function inc(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^|.)(z*)$/, (m, c, t) => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1 || "a".charCodeAt(0)) + "a".repeat(t.length))
}

for (var s of ["", "q", "z", "aa", "az", "zz", "ffff", "dzzzz", "zzzzzz", "qwzzerzzty"]) {
  console.log(s + "\n" + inc(s))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал для русского, не идеально т.к. буква `ё` "в пролёте" и цифры я не обрабатывал

```js
console.log("привет -> ", next("привет", "ая"))
console.log("ПЕТЯ -> ", next("ПЕТЯ", "ая"))

function next(w, c) {
  w = w.split('');

  for (let i = w.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (w[i] === c[1]) {
      w[i] = c[0]
    } else if (w[i] === c[1].toUpperCase()) {
      w[i] = c[0].toUpperCase()
    } else {
      w[i] = String.fromCharCode(w[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return w.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если представить строку как число в 26 (без цифр) ричной системе счисления то всё что нужно это воспользоваться алгоритмом суммирования таких чисел (прибавление 1 в нашем случае).

Допустим есть строка `qwerty` - в 26 ричной системе это `16 22 4 17 19 24`

Эти цифры получились отнимаением от каждого символа числа 97 (код символа `a` что в 26 ричной системе получается 0, а последний символ это `z` это 25, отсюда и получаем 26 ричную систему)

Решение на С++ (ссори но переводить в js думаю не составит труда)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BASE 26

void incStr(std::string& s) {
    size_t size = s.size();
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    sum = s[size-1] - 97 + 1;
    carry = sum / BASE;
    sum -= carry*BASE;
    s[size-1] = sum + 97;        
    if (carry == 0) return; // прибавление к нулям вовсе необязательно поэтому можно здесь остановится и с экономить на этих лишних итерациях

    for (int i = size-2; i > -1; --i) {
        sum = s[i] -97 + carry;
        carry = sum/BASE;
        sum -= carry*BASE;
        s[i] = sum + 97;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "qwerty";
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
        incStr(s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

p.s. 
Этот ответ это скорее как детальное пояснение ответа от @vp_arth, которое поможет разобраться глубже